# update query using join

Tags: sql, join, sql-update, informix

I need help in updating a database using a join query.It is not a straight forward query and kind of confusing.

I created a select query to select routelist(d.name) which is equal to 'TP-424-RL'.

```
select n.dnorpattern as RoutePattern, 
rp.name as Partition, 
d.name as RouteList,
rl.selectionOrder,
rg.name as RouteGroup 
from numplan as n 
inner  join routepartition as rp 
  on  rp.pkid=n.fkroutepartition 
inner join devicenumplanmap as dnpm 
  on dnpm.fknumplan=n.pkid 
inner join device as d 
  on dnpm.fkdevice=d.pkid 
inner join routelist as rl 
  on rl.fkdevice = d.pkid 
inner join routegroup as rg 
  on rg.pkid=rl.fkroutegroup and n.tkpatternusage=5 
where  d.name='TP-424-RL';
```

Similarly I want to update the routelist(d.name='SME-IT') instead of 'TP-424-RL'. the d.name(name from device table does not give routelist direclty but by the combination of the join query gives the d.name =routelist)

I tried this and it didn't work.

```
update (
select n.dnorpattern as RoutePattern, 
rp.name as Partition, 
d.name as RouteList , 
rl.selectionOrder, 
rg.name as RouteGroup 
from numplan as n 
inner join routepartition as rp 
  on  rp.pkid=n.fkroutepartition 
inner join devicenumplanmap as dnpm 
  on dnpm.fknumplan=n.pkid 
inner join device as d 
  on dnpm.fkdevice=d.pkid 
inner join routelist as rl 
  on rl.fkdevice = d.pkid 
inner join routegroup as rg 
  on rg.pkid=rl.fkroutegroup and n.tkpatternusage=5 
where d.name='TP-424-RL') set device.name='CME-IT' where device.name='TP-424-RL';
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: mysql? sql server? oracle? db2? visual fox pro? postger sql? ms access? some other rdbms I forgot to mention?

Comment: I know nothing about this database. have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: informix is similar to sql server.

Comment: When you say "It didn't work", you should give information about what error message you got, or why the result was wrong, and generally identify what happened so that other people don't have to guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the syntax of the [UPDATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) statement in Informix.  The join notation updates are not described, which is why you get errors when you attempt to use it.

You will need to use an UPDATE statement of the general form:

```
UPDATE device
   SET name = 'SME-IT' -- Or did you mean CME-IT?  The question says both
 WHERE pkid IN (SELECT ...)
```

and the ... part will be a query that identifies the primary key (or some other candidate (unique) key) of the rows in the Device table for which the current device name is `TP-424-RL` and the rows should be updated.  (I'm assuming that it isn't as simple as 'all rows where the device name is `TP-424-RL` should be updated.)

A trivial version might be:

```
UPDATE device
   SET name = 'SME-IT' -- Or did you mean CME-IT?  The question says both
 WHERE pkid IN
      (SELECT d.pkid
        FROM numplan AS n 
        JOIN routepartition AS rp 
          ON rp.pkid = n.fkroutepartition 
        JOIN devicenumplanmap AS dnpm 
          ON dnpm.fknumplan = n.pkid 
        JOIN device AS d
          ON dnpm.fkdevice = d.pkid 
        JOIN routelist AS rl 
          ON rl.fkdevice = d.pkid 
        JOIN routegroup AS rg 
          ON rg.pkid = rl.fkroutegroup AND n.tkpatternusage = 5 
       WHERE d.name='TP-424-RL'
      )
```

My suspicion is that the query can be simplified, but I'm not sure of all the details of your schema.  The `AND n.tkpatternusage = 5` condition can be moved around; it seems to belong most logically to the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT`, or perhaps the `ON` condition joining `n` to `rp` or `dnpm`.  The optimizer will move it to where it provides most bang for the buck, which is likely to be filtering on the scan of the `numplan` (aka `n`) table.

Comment: This query worked for a single update but when i want to update for a bulk update it didn't work and gives a 346 error code.soapenv:ClientCould not update a row in the table.-346Could not update a row in the table.executeSQLUpdate. 346 error code -for large transaction.Any thoughts?

Comment: Succinctly, no (I don't have any thoughts).  What was the secondary (ISAM) error?  How did you change the query?  There are too many possible causes of trouble and vastly too little information for any speculation to be possible.

Comment: No I didn't change the query. If the where condition has one transaction then it updates but if the where condition has 557 transactions it doesn't and throws a 346 error code. THis is the query I used which you gave.

Comment: update device
    set name = 'IT-SME_RL' 
        where pkid IN
       (SELECT d.pkid
        FROM numplan AS n 
        JOIN routepartition AS rp 
          ON rp.pkid = n.fkroutepartition 
        JOIN devicenumplanmap AS dnpm 
          ON dnpm.fknumplan = n.pkid 
        JOIN device AS d
          ON dnpm.fkdevice = d.pkid 
        JOIN routelist AS rl 
          ON rl.fkdevice = d.pkid 
        JOIN routegroup AS rg 
          ON rg.pkid = rl.fkroutegroup AND n.tkpatternusage = 5 
       where d.name='TP-424-RO');

Answer (score 2):

This will not work since you don't have device.name in your query. 
Also, to me it looks very strange.
I would probably do it like this: (will work with sql server, i don't know your rdbms so I go with what I know best)

```
update device
set name = 'CME-IT'
from numplan as n 
inner join routepartition as rp on  rp.pkid=n.fkroutepartition 
inner join devicenumplanmap as dnpm on dnpm.fknumplan=n.pkid 
inner join device as on dnpm.fkdevice = device.pkid 
inner join routelist as rl on rl.fkdevice = device.pkid 
inner join routegroup as rg on rg.pkid=rl.fkroutegroup and n.tkpatternusage=5 
where device.name='TP-424-RL'
```

Comment: Ya it didn't workGives  me an error 'soapenv:ClientA syntax error has occurred.-201A syntax error has occurred.executeSQLUpdate'.

Comment: So it's not that similar after all... sql server support this syntax. Try jonathan's answer. This would be much more efficient if you would have unclude the informix tag in the question fromvthe begining.

Comment: Thanks a lot Zohar for helping me

Answer (score 1):

You will need to join a replacement value withing the braces. If your query meets the requirement of an 'updatable' table you will be able to update by using the two columns